Help me find this Suspense/Thriller movie
Unfortunately, I only remember one scene; a projectile is shot into a room from a building across the street.  It's an arrow/grappling hook with a wire attached.  A guy uses it to enter a room with a safe, and then cracks the safe.  It may have been one of the Oceans movies.  The room had a lot of wood furniture in it, like bookshelves and stuff.  It may have taken place in Venice, but I'm not positive.  Movie was definitely Hollywood, probably released in late 90's/early 00's.
Does this scene sound familiar to anyone?

This sounds like ocean's twelve: 


In particular this scene above, they use the wire for a different purpose though and not to send a guy through

That's it, exactly.  Damn my failing memory!  :o)  Thanks!
